# Create IIS Website with App Pools

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a Jenkins job with a PS script which creates Web Site if it is not available. This script looks good and executes without errors. I am looking for an update to this script if I have to create an website under which I need to create applications. PFA of screen shot of my current requirement.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Function WAPublish
{
Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $RELEASEDIR,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $DESTINATION,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $SERVER,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $SITE,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $HostName,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $SitePhysicalPath,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $WebPoolPhysicalPath,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $WebApplication,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $WebPoolDestPath
    )
if(Test-Path "IIS:\Sites\$site\$WebApplication")
    {
        Write-Host "The provided website name is $site and it is a valid website`r`n" -ForegroundColor Cyan
        Copy-Item "$RELEASEDIR\*" "\\$SERVER\$WebPoolPhysicalPath" -Force -Recurse
        Write-Host "Deployment completed"
        invoke-command -computername "$SERVER" -scriptblock {iisreset /RESTART}
    }
else
    {
        Write-Host "There is not a website present in the name provided`r`n" -ForegroundColor Red
        New-Item iis:\Sites\$SITE -bindings @{protocol="http";bindingInformation=":80:$HostName"} -physicalPath $SitePhysicalPath
        New-WebApplication "$WebApplication" -Site "$SITE" -ApplicationPool "DefaultAppPool" -PhysicalPath "$WebPoolDestPath"
        Copy-Item "$RELEASEDIR\*" "\\$SERVER\$WebPoolPhysicalPath" -Force -Recurse
        invoke-command -computername "$SERVER" -scriptblock {iisreset /RESTART}
        Exit
    }
if ($error) { exit 1 }
}
WAPublish -RELEASEDIR "C:\Location" -DESTINATION "c$\Location" -SERVER "server" -SITE "LegalEntity" -HostName "Location" -SitePhysicalPath "C:\Location" -WebApplication "value" -WebPoolPhysicalPath "c$\Location" -WebPoolDestPath "C:\Location"
```

Comment: That's an application, not an application pool... Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Deadly-Bagel Yes.. I need an Web Application which has Sub applications under it

Comment: My above script will create an website but I need to create applications under that website.

Comment: You use New-WebApplication to create one, does this not work or throw an error?

Comment: @Deadly-Bagel Updated my question

Comment: Its creating Web Application but it is not copying files from Source to destination. Updated my script.

Comment: You need to narrow down the problem. Try Copy-Item on its own and check the destination to ensure it behaves as you're expecting it to.

Comment: It's very rude to spam questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570304/ps-script-to-create-a-iis-website